# Python Antlr why isnt my code coming up with the expected outcome?

Tags: python, compiler-construction, antlr, antlr4

I need to create a compiler for a custom language called Decaf. I need a python file called decaf-lexer.py, which prints the list of tokens detected by your compiler for a given input text
file. Here is my Grammar in antlr for the Lexer:

```
grammar Decaf;

//********* LEXER ******************

fragment ALPHA : [a-zA-Z];
fragment DIGIT : [0-9];
ID : ALPHA( ALPHA | DIGIT)* ;
NUM: DIGIT(DIGIT)* ;
COMMENTS: '//' ~('\r' | '\n' )*  -> skip;
WS : (' ' | '\n')+  ->skip;

LROUND : '(';
RROUND : ')';
LCURLY : '{';
RCURLY : '}';
LSQUARE: '[' ;
RSQUARE : ']';
SEMI : ';';
CLASS: 'class';
BOOLEAN : 'boolean';
BREAK : 'break';
CALLOUT : 'callout';
CONTINUE : 'continue';
ELSE : 'else';
FALSE : 'false';
FOR : 'for';
IF : 'if';
INT : 'int';
RETURN : 'return';
TRUE : 'true';
VOID : 'void';
CHAR : ALPHA|DIGIT|' '| '#' | '$' | '&' | '.' | ':' | '?' | '@' | '\\' | '^' | '_' | '`'| '|' | '~' | '\t'| '\n' ;
COMMA: ',';
COMPARE: '==';
NEQUAL: '!=';
GREQUAL: '>=';
LSEQUAL: '<=';
LS: '<';
GR: '>';
AND: '&&';
OROR: '||';
EQUALS: '=';
PEQUAL: '+=';
MEQUAL: '-=';
PLUS: '+';
MINUS: '-';
TIMES: '*';
DIVIDE: '/';
MOD: '%';
QUOTE: '"';
SQUOTE: '\'';
EXPLANATION: '!';
```

Here is the python code

```
import antlr4 as ant
from DecafLexer import DecafLexer

filein = open('example_01.decaf', 'r')
lexer = DecafLexer(ant.InputStream(filein.read()))

token = lexer.nextToken()
while token.type != -1:
    print(lexer.symbolicNames[token.type])
    token = lexer.nextToken()
```

The example file only contains:

```
(x + y)
```

The outcome is

```
LCURLY
COMMENTS
TIMES
COMMENTS
RCURLY
```

when it should be this, where am i going wrong????

```
LROUND
ID
PLUS
ID
RROUND
```

Comment: If I take the code from your question, compile the grammar, and run the test, it produces exactly the output you expect. I'm using Python 3.7.7 and Antlr 4.5.2.

Comment: I would start by looking at the generated `DecafLexer` code. For example, how LROUND, LCURLY etc are defined. I don't think it's possible to debug without seeing the relevant code. I'd also check you're reading the right file.

Comment: In my DecafLexer there is a T_0 and T_1 created before num ID ect, which is throwing everything off by two, any idea what these are???

Comment: You don't give the parser rules, but it's likely that you have two string literals in parser rules that do not have a corresponding lexer rule. Antlr generates those T_ symbols to give them a token number. Alternatively, you may want to check that you removed the .tokens file before doing a build and recheck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `symbolicNames` contains the names of the named lexer rules you defined in the order in which you defined them. However, it does not contain the lexer rules that were implicitly defined for literals you use in your parser rules. Since those will have type number that comes before those of the named rules, that means you can not use `token.type` as an index into `symbolicNames` if you use any implicit lexer rules in your grammar.

Instead you should be using `ruleNames`, which does include the implicit tokens. So for any token with a proper name `lexer.ruleNames[token.type]` will correctly return that name and for any tokens created from string literals it will return a string like `T__0`.

Comment: Ah, just now notice that Henry is using `symbolicNames` and his remark by "off by two"! I just copy-pasted his code and ran it

Answer (score 0):

When I run:

```py
lexer = DecafLexer(ant.InputStream('(x + y)'))

token = lexer.nextToken()
while token.type != -1:
    print(lexer.symbolicNames[token.type])
    token = lexer.nextToken()
```

the following is printed:

```
LROUND
ID
PLUS
ID
RROUND
```

My guess is that you haven't generated new parser- and lexer classes from your grammar.

One more thing: try tokenising the input `boolean`: you will see it is tokenised as an `ID`. This is because you have defined `ID` before all keywords (like `boolean`, `false`, `void`, ect.). IfF ANTLR can match multiple lexer rules (i.e. 2 or more rules match the same characters), the one defined first will "win".

The solution: move `ID` below all keywords:

```
CLASS: 'class';
BOOLEAN : 'boolean';
BREAK : 'break';
CALLOUT : 'callout';
CONTINUE : 'continue';
ELSE : 'else';
FALSE : 'false';
FOR : 'for';
IF : 'if';
INT : 'int';
RETURN : 'return';
TRUE : 'true';
VOID : 'void';

ID : ALPHA( ALPHA | DIGIT)* ;
```

Finally, this rule:

```
CHAR : ALPHA|DIGIT|' '| '#' | '$' | '&' | '.' | ':' | '?' | '@' | '\\' | '^' | '_' | '`'| '|' | '~' | '\t'| '\n' ;
```

is odd: it can match single space-chars, but you already instructed spaces to be skipped earlier. Also, you tell it to match a single `ALPHA` or `DIGIT`, but these are matched as an `ID` or `NUM` respectively.

> there is a T_0 and T_1 created before num ID ect, which is throwing everything off by two, any idea what these are?

If you define literal tokens inside parser rules, like this:

```
parser_rule
 : LEXER_RULE ';'
 ;
```

then this `';'` wil implicitly be defined by ANTLR like such a `T_...` token behind the scenes. But these `T_...` tokens have no impact on the suggestions from my answer though.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i have read your name multiple times while researching this, i have made the changes but In my generated DecafLexer there is a T_0 and T_1 created before num ID ect, which is throwing everything off by two, any idea what these are???